# Change position top/left of children independently of the parent scrollTop position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position

I have several divs positioned absolutely within its parent.
The parent overflows the screen and can be scrolled.

On click those divs are supposed to be positioned occupying the height of the screen (as if they had position fixed). So each div is assigned a certain width and height and a top value. The problem is this only works as expected if the parent is not scrolled (scrollTop = 0).

I want this to be done **smoothly** with CSS transitions. I could assign a top value related to the scroll position of the parent in the click moment. But **I am looking for a CSS way** to do this. I thought of changing position fixed to the divs but this doesn't transition.

Is there any way I could make it work **using CSS**?

**Edit**: I am asking if anyone has some suggestion on how to achieve this using CSS, or some thought on how to approach it differently.

[image: gif]

**Edit2**: This GIF includes just the position change (the width or height is no changing) as it is where I am having the issue. This is the desired solution:

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4utdxr0t/).

```js
var $container = $('#container');
var $elements = $container.find('.element');
$container

  .height(function() {

    return ($elements.eq(-1).position().top - $elements.eq(0).position().top + $elements.eq(0).outerHeight());

  })
  .on('click', function() {

    $elements.add($container).toggleClass('on');

  });
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  left: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.element:nth-child(2) {
  top: 130px;
}

.element:nth-child(3) {
  top: 340px;
}

.element:nth-child(4) {
  top: 550px;
}

.element:nth-child(5) {
  top: 660px;
}

.on.element {
  left: 0;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(3) {
  top: 40vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(5) {
  top: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not supposed to be working on `scrollTop = 0`

Comment: It is only looking correct on scrollTop = 0. Let me add a gif

Comment: Let me know if the GIF is not clear.

Comment: You can scroll to top on `click` handler by `window.scrollTo(0,0)`. Will this help?

Comment: It would make a jump. And then the divs would transition. So it's not what I am looking for, thanks.

Comment: So, clicking on div after scrolling, what is the desired behavior - Div#1 to go top or Div#1 to appear on top of the current viewport remaining at the same scroll Position?

Comment: Your second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding a margin-top value equivalent to the scrollTop position**, and transitioning it with the same duration and ease as the children did the trick:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4utdxr0t/4/)

```js
var $container = $('#container');
var $elements = $container.find('.element');
$container

  .height(function() {

    return ($elements.eq(-1).position().top - $elements.eq(0).position().top + $elements.eq(0).outerHeight());

  })
  .on('click', function() {

    $elements.add($container).toggleClass('on');
    $container.css('margin-top', $('body').scrollTop());

  });
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  left: 100px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.element:nth-child(2) {
  top: 130px;
}

.element:nth-child(3) {
  top: 340px;
}

.element:nth-child(4) {
  top: 550px;
}

.element:nth-child(5) {
  top: 660px;
}

.on.element {
  left: 0;
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(3) {
  top: 40vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(4) {
  top: 60vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(5) {
  top: 80vh;
}

.on.element:nth-child(6) {
  top: 25vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've already mentioned changing `position` doesn't transition. This is because `position` is a non-animatable property, i.e. animations/transitions don't work for it and so changing position from `absolute` to `relative` or vice-versa will appear *jumpy*. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) for a list of animatable properties.

You may also remove the `position: absolute` on `.element` from the beginning.

Either way, here's what you can do:

1. On clicking div, add class `on` on `#container` only and modify css with `position: relative` and `top: 0` and remove the extra rules for `top` positions
2. Add a padding of `scrollY` on `#container`, so that **Div#1** comes into current viewport if page is scrolled.

Checkout the below fiddles:

Using `relative` from beginning:
https://jsfiddle.net/4utdxr0t/2/

Switching b/w `relative` and `position`: 
https://jsfiddle.net/4utdxr0t/1/

Comment: Thank you. As there is no way to transition the position I thought a relayout somehow could work. The problem with the solutions you propose is that they "jump". What I am trying to achieve is that for example div#1 transitions from the top -250 (an example number) to top scrollTop (which is the 0 in the current screen). div#2 from top -100 to scrollTop+5vh...or some other way.  After they reposition the container will hide so I don't mind any styling changes to it.

Comment: I edited the question and added another GIF. I hope it is understandable. Thank you for the time :)